# Populate EFS with static file OR Apache Superset S3 config OR other?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, apache-superset, amazon-efs

Currently trying to define an Apache Superset distributed architecture with terraform. Its major components are:

- EFS volume that contains the config, a static python file
- ECS cluster + task def + service that runs the base apache/superset container, mounts the EFS volume, and sets the proper env variable to point to the config

The issue here is that I can't figure out how to populate the EFS volume with the config on startup. I'd have to do something like manually mount the drive on a VM, place the file, then unmount, which feels dirty.

Ideally, I'd like to leapfrog all of this and just put the config in S3, but I can't find any relevant docs to suggest that'd work, and based on my knowledge of the PYTHONPATH, it probably won't.

As a backup, I'd like to populate the EFS drive with this config file and keep all else the same, but I can't figure anything out that doesn't involve sketchy bash post build scripts or building a custom image, which I want to avoid.

Does anyone have advice?